# Kibana 4 : How to remove saved discover request

Tags: kibana-4

How to remove or clean some saved requests in the Discover tab?

Comment: I think that for the recent version of Kibana rather @АнтонАнтонов's answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go into Settings, select the Objects tab, the Searches sub-tab, hit the checkbox next to anything you want to remove, and hit the delete selected button.

Comment: I think that for the recent version of Kibana rather @АнтонАнтонов's answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 7):

In recent version of Kibana you need to go to: `Stack management` -> `Saved objects`, select the saved searches that you want to delete and press the `Delete` button.

[image]

N.B. The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/8.11/managing-saved-objects.html) also states that

> To access Saved Objects, you must have the required `Saved Objects Management` Kibana privilege.

So it is possible that the menu item is not accessible for you.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Kibana 5.6 and a filebeat, then use the follwing to delete your search using the devtools is as following

```
DELETE filebeat-*
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}

The output will be 

{
  "acknowledged": true
```

and now, if you check the discover tab, all your searches should be deleted which starts using the filebeat- index. Here you are deleting the index you created.

Comment: This is a dangerously bad answer. The question was "how to delete a previously saved search request", and I think this answer deletes all the data from the index.